# Why the file id, in telegram bot, not work after some days?

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am using telegram API and create php telegram bot. For sending video file with `sendVideo` method, use `file_id` like `BAADBAADbwADhd7gCEpUooz4V5Q1Ag`. But after some days this `file_id` not worked and I have to upload this video file again. What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as you can read in [this link](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq):

> Can I count on file_ids to be persistent?
>
> For the moment, file_ids for your bot's outgoing files may be recycled
>   after several thousand files have been sent. This may be changed in
>   the future. Inbound file_ids can be treated as persistent.

so if you send a file from your server to telegram user (over the bot), the returned `file_id` can't be permanent. you can forward the file from user to bot and save `file_id` instead of that.

Comment: That FAQ section has been updated, now (February 2018) it [says](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#can-i-count-on-file-ids-to-be-persistent): `Yes, file_ids can be treated as persistent.`

Comment: thanks @Meloman. yes the FAQ updated. but there is serious concern about files after one million! because currently **a user** and **a channel** in telegram, can't contain more than1 million files. BOT maybe too!

Comment: علیرضا forwarded id to bot are same with sended id to my user, and my id not work after some days.

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei yes, unfortunately the `forwarded` post to bot is not permanent except the post forwarded from a channel to bot not from a person.

Comment: Then Should I upload to a channel first and after that to bot? This way is permanent? Can I upload a 100 MG file and get permanent file id too?

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei yes i use this thechnique for more that 2 years! but note that each channel can not contain more that 1 milion post!!

Answer (score 1):

Telegram updated the [FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#can-i-count-on-file-ids-to-be-persistent)

> **Can I count on file_ids to be persistent?**
>
> Yes, file_ids can be treated as persistent.